# Navigation Drawer. Помощь с фрагментом

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, я использую ND в основной активности. В ND у меня подгружается список категорий объявлений с сервера. Теперь я пытаюсь реализовать метод перехода подгруженных item'ов к фрагменту, так как там буду отображать список объявлений в зависимости от выбранного item'а. Суть вопроса: Как мне правильно использовать ОДИН фрагмент для подгурзки объявлений в зависимости от выбранной категории? Что я делал, я обращаюсь к менеджеру фрагментов, затем замещаю(replace) один и тот же фрагмент и в то время через интерфейс передаю itemId фрагменту. Но беда в том что фрагмент подгружается один поверх другого или вообще не замещаются если фрагменты не записывать в стек. Направьте пожалуйста в нужное русло...как можно использовать один фрагмент "мобильно" :) Спасибо за ранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос конечно решился давно, но раз уж тут есть данный вопрос, то и ответ ему полагается. Вопрос был решён с помощью передачи аргументов в статичный метод `newInstance` во фрагмент.

```
Fragment fragment = Fragment.newInstance(ID, TITLE);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, TAG).commit();
```